# Recorrer elemento de un Hashtable en c#

Tags: c#, hash

bueno resulta que tengo un programa donde pide que el usuario ingrese un codigo de barras, nombre y precio de un producto luego estos los guardo dentro de un Hashtable y en otra clase tengo un metodo llamado validaDatos y en esta recibo como parametro el Hashtable, el cual lo recorro con un foreach, el probrema es que necesito obtener el valor de un elemento dentro del foreach y verificar que no se pase de determinada cantidad de caracteres pero no se como hacerlo.
esta es una fraccion de mi codigo:

```
  public void nuevo(){
        c.WriteLine("Ingresar codigo de barras");
        string code =c.ReadLine();

        c.WriteLine("Ingresar nombre");
        string nom =c.ReadLine();

        c.WriteLine("Ingresar precio");
        double pre =Double.Parse(c.ReadLine());

        Hashtable valores = new Hashtable();
        valores.Add("Codigo", code);
        valores.Add("Nombre", nom);
        valores.Add("Precio", pre);

        prod.store(valores);
    }
```

public class ProductController
    {
        public ProductController()
        {
        }

```
    public void store(Hashtable valores){

        ICollection keys = valores.Keys;
        foreach(Object f in keys){
            c.WriteLine(f + " = " + valores[f] );
            if(f.Equals("Codigo")){
  // Aqui necesito acceder al elemento con el key "Codigo"
  // y mandar un mensaje de error en caso de que el valor ingresado sea 
  // mayor a 13
            }else{ 

                if(f.Equals("Nombre")){

                }else{  

                    if(f.Equals("Precio")){

                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación del `Hashtable` es clara. En realidad como hereda de una colección (IDictionary), podes acceder a un elemento en particular de la misma si sabes la key.

Como al parecer, sabes la key que estas buscando, particularmente es mas fácil acceder a la misma:

Alcanza con que hagas:

```
valores["codigo"].length
```

Pero en realidad, parece que estas usando mal el `hashtable`. Si vas a guardar tres valores totalmente distintos, no tiene sentido un `Hashtable`. El mismo se usa para acceder a un objeto complejo basado en una clave que se hace "hash" (por decirlo de alguna forma).

No puedo darte mas información, ya que parece que lo que estas haciendo es totalmente erróneo, o no muy claro.